# Determining how many people have been added to a facebook group by a single member

Tags: facebook, facebook-group

I am the admin of a Facebook group and am trying to keep track of how many people each user has added. I cannot seem to nail down how I can easily write a script to:

1. Determine how many people a User has added.
2. Echo that to a file in the format `$User:$number_of_added_members`.

I've been made aware I cannot do this with the API, I am banging my head against a wall here. If anyone could at least point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is no way to get that kind of information via API.

Comment: I figured there wasn't, I was thinking more of scraping the site with wget or similar. I'll update my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Scraping is (without prior written permission) against Facebook’s ToS. What do you need this info for anyway?

Comment: I hadn't realized that, or even thought about it to be honest. I should have checked up on that. It was just for a little contest whoever aded the most members. I can achieve the same just searching for a string in waterfox but I was hoping for a more automated way.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this... 
actually i am a programmer and did it in the hard way because i needed group by users. I hoped that the graph api at least give me an xml of user with added by in order to make my code read it but it did not so what i did is just to copy the table on the members page and paste it on a txt file and make a python code read it and make a dictionary of user: number_of_users_he_added.
it was quick but there is a problem that the members page does not give u all the results, its infinity scroll and i have a lot of members.
u can write a js script that read the dom instead of copy paste or even a chrome extension but still have the problem with the infinity scroll.
if facebook provide the added by field in their graph it will be great

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can work with the site which lists all members and look for the string below the member which says "added by  on " But I'm not sure, how long this stays before it switches to "in the group since"

**Edit**
Use a crawler software like the one in *Symfony* to traverse the HTML of the page. You will need a PHP CLI for this tool. [DOMCrawler from Symfony](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html)

Comment: Currently that's what I'm trying to do, I've saved the html of the page and am trying to get what I want using grep and regex but I'm having trouble with that. And not quite sure how to go about getting the info I want into a file.